# Overlap of axis labels

Tags: r, plot, lme4, lattice

I am conducting a multi level regression model where I look at how house prices vary based on the number of rooms with my level 2 predictor being districts. When I plot the residuals using the dotplot() function I have trouble looking at the variable numbers on the axis because they are too closely spaced together. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

[image]

Comment: The figures on the Y labels are district numbers, they are not continuous. I want to increase the space between them so that they don't overlap and its easier to see which districts might be anomalies.

Comment: you may group single discrete values in buckets: ex: range 1 - values 0-100, range 2 - values 101-200 etc...